# Previous 30 Day Rolling Groupby Count

Tags: python, pandas

The data below shows emails received by different users and when they received them.

I would like to calculate by `customer_id` the number of campaign opens in the previous 30 days prior to a campaign being sent ie. `num_opens_in_last_30_days`. This is dependant on the number of campaigns a customer has opened prior to each campaign being sent within the last 30 days, not including the current value, indicated by the `opened` column.

A sample dataframe is as follows:

| customer_id | campaign_id | date_sent | opened |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1111 | 2021-02-10 | True |
| b | 1111 | 2021-02-10 | True |
| c | 1234 | 2021-02-10 | True |
| a | 2222 | 2021-02-20 | False |
| b | 2111 | 2021-02-20 | False |
| c | 2333 | 2021-02-20 | False |
| a | 3333 | 2021-04-02 | True |
| b | 3333 | 2021-04-02 | True |
| c | 3333 | 2021-04-02 | True |

The desired output is:

| customer_id | campaign_id | date_sent | num_opens_in_last_30_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1111 | 2021-02-10 | 0 |
| b | 1111 | 2021-02-10 | 0 |
| c | 1234 | 2021-02-10 | 0 |
| a | 2222 | 2021-02-20 | 1 |
| b | 2111 | 2021-02-20 | 1 |
| c | 2333 | 2021-02-20 | 1 |
| a | 3333 | 2021-04-02 | 0 |
| b | 3333 | 2021-04-02 | 0 |
| c | 3333 | 2021-04-02 | 0 |

The actual dataframe has a few hundred thousand rows of data.

As an example, you can see that when customer 'b' is sent `campaign_id` 2111 on 2021-02-20 they had opened 1 email (that being campaign 1111) but when customer 'b' was sent a cmapaign on 2021-04-02 the number is 0 because they hadn't opened any within the last 30 days when email campaign 3333 was sent to them.

If the dataframe is sorted on `date_sent` how would I go about doing this? I believe it would revolve around window functions and grouping on `user_email` but cannot figure out in which order to apply these functions and how. The `date_sent` column is not continuous as a campaign is not sent everyday.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Edit**: correcting dates as suggested

Comment: It appears that the date sent is also used as the date opened - correct? Or maybe not since 'a 1111' has a date opened of 2/10 vs 1/10 date sent.

Comment: Yes please assume date sent is the same as date opened.

Comment: I would think that **num_opens_in_last_30_days** should be 0 for customer b on 2021-02-10 wrt campaign 2111 since the last time an email was opened was 2021/01/10 which is more than 30 days prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some assumptions here but maybe this will help get you moving in the right direction.

Assumption #1: the 2021-01-10 dates in the data should be 2021-02-10.

Assumption #2: the date 2021-03-01 in your description should be 2021-04-02.

So here is the data:

```
  customer_id  campaign_id  date_sent  opened
0          a          1111 2021-02-10    True
1          b          1111 2021-02-10    True
2          c          1234 2021-02-10    True
3          a          2222 2021-02-20   False
4          b          2111 2021-02-20   False
5          c          2333 2021-02-20   False
6          a          3333 2021-04-02    True
7          b          3333 2021-04-02    True
8          c          3333 2021-04-02    True
```

Sums of opened within the last 30 days:

```
df.set_index('date_sent', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df['opened'] = df['opened'].astype('int64')

cn = lambda x: [0] + [(x[0:i] & ((x.index[i]-x.index[0:i]) \
        <= pd.Timedelta('30 days'))).sum() \
         for i in range(1, x.size)]

df['num_opens_in_last_30_days'] = \
    df.groupby('customer_id')['opened'].transform(cn)
```

df:

```
           customer_id  campaign_id  opened  num_opens_in_last_30_days
date_sent                                                             
2021-02-10          a          1111       1                          0
2021-02-10          b          1111       1                          0
2021-02-10          c          1234       1                          0
2021-02-20          a          2222       0                          1
2021-02-20          b          2111       0                          1
2021-02-20          c          2333       0                          1
2021-04-02          a          3333       1                          0
2021-04-02          b          3333       1                          0
2021-04-02          c          3333       1                          0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had to sort the df using `df.sort_index(inplace=True)` before doing the `transform.(cn)` for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a nice built-in rolling average calculator:

```
# Create rolling average
df_avg = df['column_of_interest'].ewm(span=7, min_periods=7).mean()
df_avg.dropna(inplace=True) # For first values where this won't apply
df_avg = df_avg.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'column'}) # To make a nicer presenation
X_avg = pd.DataFrame(df_avg.whatever_you_care_about)
r_avg = pd.DataFrame(df_avg.other_thing_you_care_about)
```

So use this on your groupby column and it should work.